# How display specific nodes or their names from firebase to spinner in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, android-layout

I am trying to take some specific data from my firebase database into a spinner.
Like I have some nodes in my database. I want them to appear in my spinner.

Below is the picture of those nodes encircled:

[Image of firebase database and encircled nodes need to appear in spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRf2c.png)

And for additional information, these nodes are creating from this java code that is in a separate java file.

And that java code is shown below:

```
public void addProgramAndDepartmentName(String programName, String departmentName)
{

        final DatabaseReference rootRef;
        rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {

                if ( !(snapshot.child("Program & Departments").child(programName).exists()) )
                {

                    // HashMap<String, Object> programAndDepartmentInformation = new HashMap<>();
                    // programAndDepartmentInformation.put("Program Name", programName);
                    // programAndDepartmentInformation.put("Department Name", departmentName);

                    ProgramDetails programAndDepartmentInformation = new ProgramDetails(programName, departmentName);

                    rootRef.child("Program & Departments").child(programName).push().setValue(programAndDepartmentInformation).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                        {

                            AddCourses addProgramNameToSpinnerInAddCourse = new AddCourses();
                            addProgramNameToSpinnerInAddCourse.getDataIntoSpinnerFromFirebase();
                            addProgramNameToSpinnerInAddCourse.spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            if (!task.isSuccessful())
                            {

                                Toast.makeText(AddPrograms.this, "Program and Department is not Added into Database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                            else
                            {

                                Toast.makeText(AddPrograms.this, "Program and Department name is added into Databse.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();

                            }
                        }
                    });


                }

                else if( (snapshot.child("Program & Departments").child(programName).exists()) && !(snapshot.child("Program & Departments").child(programName).child(departmentName).exists()) )
                {

                    ProgramDetails departmentInformation = new ProgramDetails();
                    departmentInformation.setDepartmentName(departmentName);

                    rootRef.child("Program & Departments").child(programName).push().setValue(departmentInformation).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                        {

                            AddCourses addProgramNameToSpinnerInAddCourse = new AddCourses();
                            addProgramNameToSpinnerInAddCourse.getDataIntoSpinnerFromFirebase();
                            addProgramNameToSpinnerInAddCourse.spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            if (!task.isSuccessful())
                            {

                                Toast.makeText(AddPrograms.this, "Program and Department is not Added into Database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                            else
                            {

                                Toast.makeText(AddPrograms.this, "Program and Department name is added into Databse.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();

                            }
                        }
                    });


                }

                else
                {

                    Toast.makeText(AddPrograms.this, "This " + programName + " already Exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loadingBar.dismiss();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error)
            {

            }
        });

}
```

And Xml code for spinner is below:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerForPrograms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="Click To Select Program Of COurse"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Day_et"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

 </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner>
```

And java code for retrieving data from firebase and displaying it into the spinner which I have done so far is below:

```
spinnerForPrograms = findViewById(R.id.spinnerForPrograms);

        spinnerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        spinnerArrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddCourses.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArrayList);
        spinnerForPrograms.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        getDataIntoSpinnerFromFirebase();


public void getDataIntoSpinnerFromFirebase()
{

        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Program & Departments").child("programName");

        listener = dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {

                for( DataSnapshot programNames:snapshot.getChildren() )
                {

                    spinnerArrayList.add(programNames.getValue().toString());

                }

                spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error)
            {



            }
        });

      }


}
```

Please guide me on how can I display the above-circled nodes into the spinner

Comment: Just to make sure, do you want the value "Ms" and "Bs" or the value inside it?

Comment: I just want the values ms and bs

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I cannot get anything into spinner and i don't know how could i get specific data into my spinner

Comment: if you only want Ms and Bs, the database reference should be:
`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Program & Departments")`